# Stream helper class for Java 8

Tags: java, stream

The company I work for is stuck with Java 8, and the Streams implementation in Java 8 is nice but somewhat rough around the edges.

Here is a helper class I cobbled together, using various snippets from the interwebs. But this worries me a bit, because I don't understand some of the `Spliterator` magic, and don't have the time to dive deeper into it. Of course I wrote tests, but it would be still reassuring to get some feedback.

```
package com.acme;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public final class Streams {

    private Streams() {
        // do not instantiate
    }

    public static <A, B, C> Stream<C> zipWith(Stream<A> leftStream, Stream<B> rightStream,
            BiFunction<A, B, C> combiner) {
        Spliterator<A> lefts = leftStream.spliterator();
        Spliterator<B> rights = rightStream.spliterator();
        return StreamSupport
                .stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<C>(Long.min(lefts.estimateSize(), rights.estimateSize()),
                        lefts.characteristics() & rights.characteristics()) {
                    @Override
                    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super C> action) {
                        return lefts.tryAdvance(
                                left -> rights.tryAdvance(right -> action.accept(combiner.apply(left, right))));
                    }
                }, leftStream.isParallel() || rightStream.isParallel());
    }

    public static <A, C> Stream<C> zipWithIndex(Stream<A> leftStream, BiFunction<A, Integer, C> combiner) {
        return zipWith(leftStream, Stream.iterate(0, index -> index + 1), combiner);
    }

    public static <A> Stream<A> takeWhile(Stream<A> stream, Predicate<? super A> predicate) {
        Spliterator<A> spliterator = stream.spliterator();
        return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<A>(spliterator.estimateSize(), 0) {
            boolean stillGoing = true;
            @Override
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super A> consumer) {
                if (stillGoing) {
                    boolean hadNext = spliterator.tryAdvance(elem -> {
                        if (predicate.test(elem)) {
                            consumer.accept(elem);
                        } else {
                            stillGoing = false;
                        }
                    });
                    return hadNext && stillGoing;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }, false);
    }

    public static <A> Stream<A> dropWhile(Stream<A> stream, Predicate<? super A> predicate) {
        Spliterator<A> spliterator = stream.spliterator();
        return StreamSupport.stream(new Spliterators.AbstractSpliterator<A>(spliterator.estimateSize(), 0) {
            boolean dropped;
            public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super A> action) {
                if (dropped) {
                    return spliterator.tryAdvance(action);
                }
                while (true) {
                    if (!(!dropped && spliterator.tryAdvance(t -> {
                        if (!predicate.test(t)) {
                            dropped = true;
                            action.accept(t);
                        }
                    }))) break;
                }
                return dropped;
            }
            public void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super A> action) {
                while (!dropped) {
                    if (!tryAdvance(action)) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                spliterator.forEachRemaining(action);
            }
        }, false);
    }

    public static <A> Stream<A> from(Iterable<A> iterable) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
    }

    public static <A> Stream<A> from(Optional<A> optional) {
        return optional.map(Stream::of).orElseGet(Stream::empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe a bit off-topic in CodeReview, but I would advise to re-use a lib like https://github.com/amaembo/streamex for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I've made similar Stream extensions in the past. However, I had used a decorator pattern. That way, the ability to chain stream operations (including the ones you add) remains intact. (this does not apply to the `from()` methods)
- In `zipWith()`, I'd consider it more prudent to specify :

  ```
  leftStream.isParallel() && rightStream.isParallel()
  ```

  If either stream is not parallel, someone may have used operations on it, that are not suitable for parallel processing.
- in `dropWhile()`, it is unnecessary to override `forEachRemaining`. the default implementation delegates to `tryAdvance`, and that works just fine.